# Java, Spring Internationalization(I18N) not working

Tags: java, spring, internationalization

I am trying to change my spring projects language with I18N.

my configuration for I18N in spring-servlet.xml:

```
<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
</bean>

<bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
    <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
</bean>

<bean id="localeResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="en"/>
</bean>

<bean id="handlerMapping"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
    <property name="interceptors">
        <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

so now I have 2 properties files named:

1. messages_en.properties
2. messages_ee.properties

**They are in my war/WEB-INF/resources folder**

This is part of my JSP file(**when i remove it, everything works**):

```
<h3><spring:message code="label.title" /></h3>
```

This is my messages_ee.properties file:

```
label.firstname=Eesnimi
label.lastname=Perekonnanimi
label.email=Email
label.telephone=Telefon
label.addcontact=Lisa kontakt

label.menu=Menuu
label.title=Kontaktihaldur
```

**You can clearly see, that I have label.title for locale 'ee'. What could be problem, that it does not recognize it. Or furthermore, maybe it does not even find the file?**

It can not find label.title for locale 'ee', WHY?

When I try to browse on certain web, it says it does not find anything in the properties file with this error:

```
HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /index.jsp at line 1

1: <jsp:forward page="contact.html"></jsp:forward>


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:567)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:456)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:389)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:333)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
root cause

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.apache.tiles.impl.CannotRenderException: ServletException including path '/WEB-INF/jsp/layout.jsp'.
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:656)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doForward(PageContextImpl.java:745)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.forward(PageContextImpl.java:716)
    org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:63)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:433)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:389)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:333)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
root cause

org.apache.tiles.impl.CannotRenderException: ServletException including path '/WEB-INF/jsp/layout.jsp'.
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:692)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:644)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:627)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:321)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView.renderMergedOutputModel(TilesView.java:124)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1047)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:817)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doForward(PageContextImpl.java:745)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.forward(PageContextImpl.java:716)
    org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:63)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:433)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:389)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:333)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
root cause

org.apache.tiles.util.TilesIOException: ServletException including path '/WEB-INF/jsp/layout.jsp'.
    org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletUtil.wrapServletException(ServletUtil.java:241)
    org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.forward(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:243)
    org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.dispatch(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:222)
    org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.TemplateAttributeRenderer.write(TemplateAttributeRenderer.java:44)
    org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:670)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:690)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:644)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:627)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:321)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView.renderMergedOutputModel(TilesView.java:124)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1047)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:817)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doForward(PageContextImpl.java:745)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.forward(PageContextImpl.java:716)
    org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:63)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:433)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:389)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:333)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
root cause

org.apache.tiles.util.TilesIOException: JSPException including path '/WEB-INF/jsp/header.jsp'.
    org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletUtil.wrapServletException(ServletUtil.java:241)
    org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.include(JspTilesRequestContext.java:105)
    org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.dispatch(JspTilesRequestContext.java:96)
    org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.TemplateAttributeRenderer.write(TemplateAttributeRenderer.java:44)
    org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)
    org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.ChainedDelegateAttributeRenderer.write(ChainedDelegateAttributeRenderer.java:76)
    org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:670)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:336)
    org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.renderAttribute(InsertAttributeModel.java:210)
    org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.end(InsertAttributeModel.java:126)
    org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.doTag(InsertAttributeTag.java:311)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.layout_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_005finsertAttribute_005f1(layout_jsp.java:142)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.layout_jsp._jspService(layout_jsp.java:78)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:433)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:389)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:333)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.forward(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:241)
    org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.dispatch(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:222)
    org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.TemplateAttributeRenderer.write(TemplateAttributeRenderer.java:44)
    org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:670)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:690)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:644)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:627)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:321)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView.renderMergedOutputModel(TilesView.java:124)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1047)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:817)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doForward(PageContextImpl.java:745)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.forward(PageContextImpl.java:716)
    org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:63)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:433)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:389)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:333)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
root cause

javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: No message found under code 'label.title' for locale 'ee'.
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:911)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:840)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.header_jsp._jspService(header_jsp.java:83)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:433)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:389)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:333)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:927)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:684)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:678)
    org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.include(JspTilesRequestContext.java:103)
    org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.dispatch(JspTilesRequestContext.java:96)
    org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.TemplateAttributeRenderer.write(TemplateAttributeRenderer.java:44)
    org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)
    org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.ChainedDelegateAttributeRenderer.write(ChainedDelegateAttributeRenderer.java:76)
    org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:670)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:336)
    org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.renderAttribute(InsertAttributeModel.java:210)
    org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.end(InsertAttributeModel.java:126)
    org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.doTag(InsertAttributeTag.java:311)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.layout_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_005finsertAttribute_005f1(layout_jsp.java:142)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.layout_jsp._jspService(layout_jsp.java:78)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:433)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:389)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:333)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.forward(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:241)
    org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.dispatch(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:222)
    org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.TemplateAttributeRenderer.write(TemplateAttributeRenderer.java:44)
    org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:670)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:690)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:644)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:627)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:321)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView.renderMergedOutputModel(TilesView.java:124)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1047)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:817)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doForward(PageContextImpl.java:745)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.forward(PageContextImpl.java:716)
    org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:63)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:433)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:389)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:333)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
root cause

javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: No message found under code 'label.title' for locale 'ee'.
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.MessageTag.doStartTagInternal(MessageTag.java:184)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:79)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.header_jsp._jspx_meth_spring_005fmessage_005f0(header_jsp.java:102)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.header_jsp._jspService(header_jsp.java:69)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:433)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:389)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:333)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:927)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:684)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:678)
    org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.include(JspTilesRequestContext.java:103)
    org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.dispatch(JspTilesRequestContext.java:96)
    org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.TemplateAttributeRenderer.write(TemplateAttributeRenderer.java:44)
    org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)
    org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.ChainedDelegateAttributeRenderer.write(ChainedDelegateAttributeRenderer.java:76)
    org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:670)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:336)
    org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.renderAttribute(InsertAttributeModel.java:210)
    org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.end(InsertAttributeModel.java:126)
    org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.doTag(InsertAttributeTag.java:311)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.layout_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_005finsertAttribute_005f1(layout_jsp.java:142)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.layout_jsp._jspService(layout_jsp.java:78)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:433)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:389)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:333)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.forward(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:241)
    org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.dispatch(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:222)
    org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.TemplateAttributeRenderer.write(TemplateAttributeRenderer.java:44)
    org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:670)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:690)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:644)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:627)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:321)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView.renderMergedOutputModel(TilesView.java:124)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1047)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:817)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doForward(PageContextImpl.java:745)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.forward(PageContextImpl.java:716)
    org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:63)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:433)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:389)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:333)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.20 logs.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.20
```

I tried to give as much information as possible and go into details. Feel free to ask further info/code.

Comment: The separator between the message name and the locales should be `_` and not `-`. Is that a typo?

Comment: So problem still exists?

Comment: Couple of things I see possibly wrong with the set up - 1) Are you passing yourUrl?lang=ee in the actual request? 2) Do you have a cookie set on the client for CookieLocaleResolver? Otherwise it will not know what locale to pick up.

Comment: @CoolBeans : 1) umm you mean in controller?  2) the only place where im using CookieLocaleResolver in configure file..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you configured the message source to look for the property files in the classpath ("classpath:messages"). The folder you are using "/WEB-INF/resources" is not part of the classpath per default. So my guess is that if you move the property files to /WEB-INF/classes (in the extracted war) it should work. Or you try to change the property for basename from "classpath:messages" to "/WEB-INF/resources/messages". But I am not sure if that will work.

Jens

Comment: Actually that worked, but now I am stuck with the same thing, but with themes... lol

Answer (score 1):

Put messages.properties files in src folder.

Answer (score 0):

I am using netbeans. To solve this problem I have moved `.properties` files from `SpringDemo\src\java\resources\messages_en.properties` to `SpringDemo\src\java\messages_en.properties` and it worked.

After deployment now it is packaging the resource file directly in classes folder instead of classes/resources folder.